# Retrieve Values for All Sheets in Google Spreadsheet for Particular Revision

Tags: google-apps-script

This is a [sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JqbuqOQS5NSFqfPlxJG-DY1HIW9xZl_ddjQa_F2pUv4/edit?usp=sharing) spreadsheet with 2 sheets (Sheet1 and Sheet2). The cell values are
1) [["This", "is", "first", "sheet"], ["Added row 2", "", "", ""]] for Sheet1
2) [["This", "is", "second", "sheet"], ["Added row 2", "", "", ""]] for Sheet2

When I run the following code,

```
var file_id = '1JqbuqOQS5NSFqfPlxJG-DY1HIW9xZl_ddjQa_F2pUv4';
var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(file_id);
var revision = revisions.items[revisions.items.length-1];

var revUrl = Drive.Revisions.get(file_id, revision.id).exportLinks["text/csv"]  + "&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

var revString = UrlFetchApp.fetch(revUrl).getContentText();
```

I only get revString = "This,is,first,sheet\nAdded row 2,,,"

How can I get the second sheet values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the latest revision.

  - This is from `var revision = revisions.items[revisions.items.length-1]`.
  - You want to also retrieve CSV data from other revisions.
- You want to retrieve CSV data from all sheets for a certain revision.
- You want to use Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

### Issue:

Unfortunately, CSV data from all sheets cannot be retrieved from `revUrl` of your script. The default endpoint of `exportLinks["text/csv"]` indicates 1st tag of the Spreadsheet. If you want to retrieve other sheets, it is required to add the query parameter of `gid={sheetId}` for each sheet.

And in the current stage, the Spreadsheet of ceatain revision cannot be directly accessed using Spreadsheet Service and Sheets API. So when the CSV data is retrieved from the revision data, if the existing sheets had already been removed and/or new sheets had already been added, all sheet IDs cannot be retrieved.

### Workaround 1:

> This workaround supposes the condition that the sheets in the Spreadsheet are removed and added.

In this modification, I used the following flow.

1. Retrieve XLSX data from the Spreadsheet of a certain revision.
2. Convert XLSX data to Google Spreadsheet as a temporal Spreadsheet.
3. Retrieve all values from the converted Spreadsheet as CSV data.
4. Delete temporal Spreadsheet.

By above flow, CSV data from all sheets with the certain revision can be retrieved.

#### Modified script:

```
var file_id = '1JqbuqOQS5NSFqfPlxJG-DY1HIW9xZl_ddjQa_F2pUv4';
var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(file_id);
var revision = revisions.items[revisions.items.length-1];

// I modified following script.
var revUrl = Drive.Revisions.get(file_id, revision.id).exportLinks["application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"]  + "&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(revUrl).getBlob();
var tempSSId = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, blob).id;
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(tempSSId).getSheets();
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  var csv = sheets[i].getDataRange().getValues().map(function(e) {return e.join(",")}).join("\n");
  Logger.log(csv)
}
Drive.Files.remove(tempSSId);
```

### Workaround 2:

> This workaround supposes the condition that the sheets in the Spreadsheet are not removed and not added.

In this modification, I used the following flow.

1. Retrieve all sheet IDs from the current Spreadsheet.
2. Create requests using retrieved sheet IDs.
3. Retrieve CSV data from each sheet.

By above flow, CSV data from all sheets with the certain revision can be retrieved.

#### Modified script:

```
var file_id = '1JqbuqOQS5NSFqfPlxJG-DY1HIW9xZl_ddjQa_F2pUv4';
var sheetIds = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file_id).getSheets().map(function(e) {return e.getSheetId()});
var token =  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(file_id);
var revision = revisions.items[revisions.items.length-1];
var reqs = sheetIds.map(function(e) {
  var revUrl = Drive.Revisions.get(file_id, revision.id).exportLinks["text/csv"]  + "&access_token=" + token + "&gid=" + e;
  return {url: revUrl, muteHttpExceptions: true};
});
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(reqs);
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
  if (res[i].getResponseCode() == 200 ) {
    Logger.log(res[i].getContentText())
  }
}
```

### Note:

- This answer supposes that Drive API is enabled at Advanced Google Services.

### References:

- [Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)
- [Files: delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/delete)
- [fetchAll()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Exactly what I needed :)

Comment: @Michael Lam I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.