# Iterate through all previous versions of Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I want to iterate through all previous versions of a Google sheet and extract some information from all the versions along with version timestamp.

Is there any easy to do so? I couldn't find any API which could loop through the previous versions.

Comment: Are these thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56213790/7108653 https://stackoverflow.com/q/57387113/7108653

Comment: @Tanaike these are both useful but also both assume that you know the revisionId. Is there any way to loop through all revisions to find the appropriate one (e.g. using the time stamp)? ps. I'm unable to use the user interface here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/get due to admin settings, so won't be able to look there for the Id.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `Revision.list` [method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list) to retrieve the Revision history of a file. Referencing this answer from a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180902/how-can-i-get-the-revision-history-in-google-docs-using-a-script) looks like you will need to download and re-upload back the file so you can have the specific version that you want available as there is no way to make a copy programatically using the [Revisions Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions).

Comment: Every time I run revision.list I only get the latest version of the file and list.lenght is equal to one. Do you know how to list the different versions that you would see in the gui?

Comment: My results are limited to three for a file that has thousands of revisions :(